# The diffeomorphism between two sub-level sets

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth map ($f \in C^{\infty}(M)$), where $M$ is a compact manifold .

Prove that $f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is diffeomorphic to $f^{-1}((-\infty,b])$ if the interval $[a,b]$ doesn't contain critical values of $f$.

I have no idea how to deal with this now and really need some hints. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the gradiant flow... Pick any standard book on Morse theory (you can approximate any smooth function by Morse function)

Comment: This is theorem 2.1.7 of Audin & Damian's *Morse Theory and Floer Homology*. One sublevel is retracted onto the other using the flow of the pseudo-gradient.

Comment: As @AnubhavMukherjee says, "Pick any standard book on Morse theory . . ."; try ***Morse Theory*** by John Milnor . . . a classic in the field.